# Add new column to data frame with certain format

Tags: r, dataframe

I have a sample data frame below:

```
df <- data.frame(ID=c("131","156","178","196"), Date=c("03/31/2016","03/31/2016","03/31/2016","03/31/2016"))
df
   ID       Date
1 131 03/31/2016
2 156 03/31/2016
3 178 03/31/2016
4 196 03/31/2016
```

I'd like to add a new column to this data frame with the format like this: `=BDH("ID CUSIP", "PX_Last","Date")`. The new data frame should look like:

```
   ID       Date  NewCol
1 131 03/31/2016  =BDH("131 CUSIP", "PX_Last", "03/31/2016")
2 156 03/31/2016  =BDH("156 CUSIP", "PX_Last", "03/31/2016")
3 178 03/31/2016  =BDH("178 CUSIP", "PX_Last", "03/31/2016")
4 196 03/31/2016  =BDH("196 CUSIP", "PX_Last", "03/31/2016")
```

As you can see, `ID` and `Date` are from the existing data frame but the words `CUSIP` and `PX_Last` are not. Please help and thank you!

Comment: `df$NewCol <- paste0('=BHD("', df$ID, ' CUSIP", "PX_Last", ', df$Date)`

Comment: This may be an [X Y Problem](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem). Will the `NewCol` syntax be used further in your code by `eval(parse(text=df$NewCol))` or a variation of it?

Comment: Thank you all for the prompt response. `paste0` solved my issue perfectly!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Would this be all right?

```
df$NewCol <- paste0("=BDH(\"", df$ID, " CUSIP\", \"PX_Last\", \"", df$Date, "\")")
```

Comment: Solved my issue perfectly. Thank you so much!